# Getting error while accessing obb file

Tags: java, android, apk-expansion-files

I am using file expansion in my project to access audio, video and image files from obb folder.
My Obb file is the form:
main.1.com.example.sample--->containg three folders with the name Images, Video and Audio--->Now it contains different .mp4,.mp3,.jpg files
I have my obb file in Android/obb/com.example.sample/main.1.com.example.sample
Now, I am trying to access .mp4 file inside Video folder by using following code:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = null;
    try {
        expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this,1,0);
         Log.e("expansion",">>>>>"+expansionFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(expansionFile!=null){
            AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("Video/v1.mp4");
            Log.e("AFDDDDDDDD",">>>>>"+fd);
        }
```

but I am getting exception:
07-30 16:14:24.685: D/zipro(22542): Zip: EOCD not found, /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.example.sample/main.1.com.example.sample.obb is not zip

> 07-30 16:14:24.685: W/zipro(22542): bad offsets (dir 191367812, size 1771611666, eocd -1)
>   07-30 16:14:24.685: W/System.err(22542): java.io.IOException
>   07-30 16:14:24.695: W/System.err(22542):    at com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile.addPatchFile(ZipResourceFile.java:353)
>   07-30 16:14:24.695: W/System.err(22542):    at com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile.(ZipResourceFile.java:189)
>   07-30 16:14:24.695: W/System.err(22542):    at com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APKExpansionSupport.getResourceZipFile(APKExpansionSupport.java:67)
>   07-30 16:14:24.695: W/System.err(22542):    at com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(APKExpansionSupport.java:77)

and not able to access directly from obb file. Please, suggest a solution and why this exception I am getting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad Offesets exception occurs when file path of obb is wrong from where assetfiledescriptor is taken out. That's why it was giving this error at runtime.